# Calculating the probability that the two children are of the same gender

Tags: probability

In a certain family,there are $3$ girls and $2$ boys.  Two children are chosen randomly to attend a birthday party. Calculate the probability that the two children chosen are of the same gender?.

This my working but I couldn't get the answer. $p(2/5) + p(2/5)=4/5$

Comment: No I can't proceed from there.Am still stuck upto there

Comment: elcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: This my working but I couldn't get the answer..P(2/5) + p(2/5)=4/5

Comment: I do not understand the reasoning behind your attempt.  The idea here is that the favorable cases involve selecting two of the three girls or two of the three boys.  The sample space is the set of all ways of selecting two of the five children.

Answer (score 0):

First note that the total number of combinations of $2$ children out of the $5$ children are $^5C_2 = 10$.

Now there are two possibilities i.e. the selected children are either both boys or both girls. The number of combinations of $2$ boys out of $2$ is $^2C_2 = 1$, while combinations of $2$ girls out of $3$ is $^3C_2 = 3$. So total combinations of the required event are $4$. So probability is
$$P = \frac4{10}=\frac25$$